# Hit the footpath with brand new winter tire

Tags: tires

[image]
Hi please help,
I just change to be winter tire 2 weeks ago and today my left front tire just hit the comer and it has 2 cracks line ( about 2 inches long )  and each one about 15 centimetres apart. And I have to drive only in motorway to get my kid school. And now I am afraid hat is it safe to drive 110-120 km/h . Do I need to fix or change it immediately. Thanks for your answers![image][image: enter image description here![enter image description here]

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: I have to believe that is a tire warranty issue. Check the fine print on your warranty. My guess is likely manufacturing related issue.

Answer (score 3):

When it is a question of safety, I will always recommend replacement, *especially with kids in the car!* Chances are there’s not real damage to the tires integrity, but it is possible. Personally, I won’t leave anything to chance when it comes to the safety of myself or others, especially my family.